# Retriving more data if found data is not sufficent. Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

My table looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (
 firstname text,
 surname text,
 id text,
 PRIMARY KEY (firstname, surname)
)
```

Let's say I want to return a minimum of 10 names.
I do

```
select * from names where firstname = "something" and surname "something";
```

But if this only returns 6 people, I then want it to do:

```
select * from names where firstname = "something" limit 4;
```

But I want to avoid returning the same row twice.
And possibly do it in one query only.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use SELECT "DISTINCT" feature of CQLSH. you will get unique value for partitions. Also please refer below documentations for more understanding:-
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlSelect.html

Comment: Thanks that helps a bunch. Though I still wonder how I can query multiple times if I did not get enough data back.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the paging implemented by driver(s), for example, in [Java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/paging/).

In your case, you can perform query, and use `.setFetchSize` when performing specific query to some value you need - in this case, driver will read approximately specified number (or less) as a first page, and if you'll need more, then you can proceed iterating over results, and driver will fetch next page, until either you stop, or there will be no more data.

But be very careful with too low values of the page - if you have a lot of data in partition, then driver will need to go to Cassandra very often, and this will impact performance.

P.S. you can't have 10 records for query `where firstname = "something" and surname = "something"`, because both columns comprise full primary key, and there could be only one record for given primary key.  You may use something like `where firstname = "something" and surname >= "something"` to fetch data starting with given surname.